# How to allow only one user at a time to execute insert trigger in a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, concurrency, triggers, sql-insert, uniqueidentifier

I have a table as follows

```
customerid name total_salary basicpay cca tax    TransactionID
---------------------------------------------------------------
101         x    12000          5000  1000 1000    2018101
102         y    15000          6000  1200 1200    2018101
```

Whenever I insert a new record, I calculate `total_salary` and create unique sequential transaction id based on year using insert trigger.

In production, the table will be used by multiple users at the same time simultaneously. When an insert of a record into the table happens, it creates duplicate transaction id as multiple users accessing/inserting the table simultaneously

The transaction id logic is:

```
Transaction ID= current year+record count in the current year+1
```

How to allow only one user at a time to execute an insert trigger on that table, so that a unique transaction id will be created?

Comment: For trasnaction ID why not use an auto increment ID on your table ID?  You can still have the year and record count saved but dont use those as your unique ID, use Primary Key and Auto increment

Comment: Hi Brad, great thanks, I accept primary key and auto increment unless I use year based unique id generation. But How to provide unique and sequential id based on year basis?. For eg. if year 2019 start, the id should start with 2019101.

Comment: I know you can seed the value for auto increment (meaning start at a specific number.  So you could set the seed value to be 2019000 for 2019, then every ID after that would incrmeent by 1.  It wouldnt have the month, then at start of new year you can change the auto increment seed value to the new year.  But if you had too many in 1 year it could change 2019 to 2020 too soon, so you may need to have a bigint and have it be something like 20190000000 (or something depending on what you expect)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it is very helpful. :) cheers.